# Coin flips with two fair coins and one biased coin

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I encountered this problem:

> We have three coins, two fair coins and one coin with heads on each
>   face.  One coin is picked randomly among those three coins and is
>   flipped two times. We see the sequence: H, H.  What is the probability
>   of obtaining heads if we flip this coin one more time?

To tackle it, here's my reasoning:

1. Find the probabilities of the coin being fair and unfair conditional on the sequence: H, H.
2. Find the probability of getting a heads in the additional flip conditional on the sequence: H, H.

1)
Using Bayes formula we have:
\begin{align}
P(fair|HH) &= \frac{P(HH|fair)P(fair)}{P(HH|fair)P(fair)+P(HH|unfair)P(unfair)}
\\ &= \frac{\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{3}+1\cdot\frac{1}{3}}
\\ &= \frac{1/6}{1/6+1/3}
\\ &= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}
We get at the same time:
\begin{align}
P(unfair|HH) = 1 - 1/3 = 2/3
\end{align}

2) Let's denote $A$ the event of obtaining of heads at the additional flip. We have:
\begin{align}
P(A) = P(A|fair)P(fair) + P(A|unfair)P(unfair)
\end{align}
and conditioning on the sequence $H,H$ we get:
\begin{align}
P(A|HH) &= P(A|fair,HH)P(fair|HH) + P(A|unfair,HH)P(unfair|HH)
\\&= P(A|fair)P(fair|HH) + P(A|unfair) P(unfair|HH)
\end{align}
We then get:
\begin{align}
P(A|HH) &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} + 1\cdot\frac{2}{3}
\\ P(A|HH) &= \frac{5}{6}
\end{align}

Is my reasoning correct? Is there maybe a quicker way to get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. A shorter way of writing it:
Let $H_n$ denote the event that we get $H$ at the $n$-th coin toss. Hence, we want the probability $$P(H_3 \vert (H_1 \cap H_2))=\frac{P(H_1 \cap H_2 \cap H_3)}{P(H_1 \cap H_2)}=\frac{P(H_1 \cap H_2\cap H_3 \vert fair)\cdot P(fair)+ P(H_1 \cap H_2\cap H_3 \vert unfair)\cdot P(unfair)}{P(H_1 \cap H_2 \vert fair)\cdot P(fair)+ P(H_1 \cap H_2 \vert unfair)\cdot P(unfair)}=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^3 \cdot \frac{2}{3}+1^3\cdot \frac{1}{3}}{(\frac{1}{2})^2 \cdot \frac{2}{3}+1^2\cdot \frac{1}{3}}=\frac{5}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar concept, but perhaps simpler:

Say the coins are $A,B,C$ with $C$ the unfair one.

There are three ways to get the outcome $HH$.

You could pick $C$ (probability $\frac 13$) and then get $HH$ (probability $1$).

You could pick $A$ (probability $\frac 13$) and then get $HH$ (probability $\frac 14$).

You could pick $B$ (probability $\frac 13$) and then get $HH$ (probability $\frac 14$).

Thus the total probability of getting $HH$ is $$\frac 13+2\times \frac 1{12}=\frac 12$$

Of this, $\frac 13$ is explained by having chosen the unfair coin so the probability that you have the unfair coin is $\frac 23$ and the probability that you have one of the fair coins is $\frac 13$.  Thus the probability that the next toss is $H$ is $$\frac 23\times 1+\frac 13\times \frac 12=\frac 56$$

Comment: $\frac 23\times 1+\frac 13\times \frac 12=\frac 56$ Is this part not clear at all? ahh

Comment: @heiverjust  Is it clear?  The computation has two parts.  Letting $p_u$ be the probability you have the unfair coin, and $p_f=1-p_u$ the probability you have the fair coin, we first use Bayes' Theorem to find $p_u, p_f$.  Then we note that the probability that the next one is $H$ is $p_u\times  1+p_f\times \frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct and that's the answer I got as well. It's pretty much the simplest way I know how to get it. You can use Bayes Theorem to get the unfair probability directly, but that doesn't cut orders of time off of the calculation or anything.